# PHP: Remove everything before the first '-'

Tags: php, substr, strpos, strlen

I want to remove some text from my title (using wordpress).
Example: Alexandra Stan - Mr. Saxobeat 
Output: Mr. Saxobeat

I tried many codes, one of this work perfect:

```
$str = "this comes before – this comes after";
$char =  " - "; 
$strpos = strpos($str, $char); 
$str = substr($str, $strpos+strlen($char)); 
echo $str;
```

but after many times of trying and get upsed... i see that in my wordpress article page, when i type "-" in title, wordpress change it automatically with: "–" who is different (bigger) than normal one "-" (copy in another font and you will see the difference).

I try replace "-" with "–" but output is " **s comes before - this comes after** "

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an [em dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) you're trying to replace. However, you're looking for a regular dash. Try running the string through this mess of code first and reading the [blog article](http://www.toao.net/48-replacing-smart-quotes-and-em-dashes-in-mysql) I got it from

**EDIT**

A complete working example, basically pasting the example code from the blog article and fixing a small mistake with your `substr`

```
function scrub_bogus_chars(&$text) {
    // First, replace UTF-8 characters.
    $text = str_replace(
    array("\xe2\x80\x98", "\xe2\x80\x99", "\xe2\x80\x9c", "\xe2\x80\x9d", "\xe2\x80\x93",      "\xe2\x80\x94", "\xe2\x80\xa6"),
    array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
    $text);

    // Next, replace their Windows-1252 equivalents.
    $text = str_replace(
    array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(150), chr(151), chr(133)),
    array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
    $text);
}

// Original string (with em dash)
$text = "this comes before – this comes after";

// Ensure regular dashes will be available
scrub_bogus_chars($text);

// Lastly, extract the interesting part of the original string
$char   =  ' - ';
$strpos = strpos($text, $char); 
$text   = substr($text, $strpos + strlen($char)); 
echo $text . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: +1: for actually reading the question (though, your code looks like ars .. I guess it cannot be helped) `=/`

Comment: @note This works for regular dashes and em dashes.

Comment: @tereško The code was mostly cut and paste, but I've just cleaned it up some for the hell of it ;)

Comment: Whoever entered the data, it's probably their fault. I first ran into this working with clients who have Windows and are pasting things from MS Word... Honestly I don't think that's much code. You could put the piece from the blog article in a function and forget about the details.

Comment: It's not a Wordpress char, read the Wikipedia article or the blog article I mentioned. Also, I've redone the solution with a function.

Answer (score 1):

You should use explode :

```
$str = "Alexandra Stan - Mr. Saxobeat ";
$char =  " - ";
$str = explode($char, $str);
echo $str[1];
```

Returns

> Mr. Saxobeat

Comment: That won't catch the em dash in his source string, which looks like the real problem.

Comment: @quickshiftin : I am sorry, i am french, i cannot understand what you mean by "em dash"
edit : ok got it, you are right what i have posted don't take care of this

Answer (score 0):

It is not a normal dash `-` it is a special utf8 char `–`. You need to use the special char in your code. With `explode()` :

```
$parts = explode(' – ', 'this comes before – this comes after');
echo $parts[1];
```

Or with `preg_match()`:

```
preg_match('~\– (.*)~', 'this comes before – this comes after', $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Or you could have a more generic solution like mine, which works with regular dashes or em dashes.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
echo explode($char, $str)[1];
```